# v.generalize along tile edges

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, vector, generalization

I have a problem with v.generalize and I hope I can find help here.

**So what I'm trying to do is the following**: I have a large number of 1x1 km tiles of rasters that represent traffic areas (roads, footways etc.). To further work with the data I vectorize it using r.to.vect in Qgis and then I generalize the resulting shapes with v.generalize to get rid of the rastery edges. This works fine on most parts of my data.

**The problem**: v.generalize is also generalizing the polygons that are at the edges of the former raster tiles. Resulting in larger cut outs from my data. So I would like v.generalize to not generalize the lines that are on the edge of my tiles.

[image: See the cut out parts of the polygons that are on he edges of the tiles]

Is there a way to exclude portions of polygons or whole polygons from the generalization? An idea I had was to use the WHERE clause built into v.generalize. I also exported the edges of the tiles as a line shapefile to try to include that into the v.generalize WHERE clause to only generalize polygons that do not touch the edges of the tiles. But I couldn't get it to work.

I'm using QGIS 3.34 and the douglas reduction method with a threshold of 0.25 and reduction 50.

Comment: Did you try some of the other methods and thresholds or were they otherwise unsuitable for your needs?  Did you get an error map for your missing areas?  I always check the geometry and run a v.clean if I have issues with other tools and sometimes they work.

Comment: You might consider to create first a virtual raster (*.vrt) of all tiles using the `gdalbuildvrt` tool. Then define that vrt inside grass using `r.external`. And then do your vectorizing and generalizing.